# Zeroes in a 3x3 Matrix Determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, factoring

My professor found the cubic roots of a 3x3 matrix by doing the following.  I don't understand how step 2 came about and why he applied the same for step 4 on row 1 instead of row 2.

Step 1:

$\begin{bmatrix}
a & 2 & 2 \\
2 & a & 2 \\
2 & 2 & a
\end{bmatrix}$

Step 2:

$=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 2 & 2 \\
2 & a & 2 \\
0 & 2-a & a-2
\end{bmatrix}$

Step 3:

$=(a-2) \begin{bmatrix}
a & 2 & 2 \\
2 & a & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

Step 4:

$=(a-2)^2\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 \\
2 & a & 2 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

He then solved for the determinant with the remaining terms.  The transition from step 1 to 2 is what is confusing me the most at the moment.  I was under the impression that there was no easy way to find the cubic roots within a matrix.

Comment: What are "the cubic roots within a matrix"? Do you mean the zeros of the cubic characteristic polynomial of a $3\times3$ matrix? Also, it seems that your formulas refer to determinants; the usual notation for determinants is with vertical bars, not with square brackets, which are usually used for the matrices themselves.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

I am aware that he simply solves for the determinant, but I do not understand how he was able to transition from step 1 to 2.  Why was he able to substitute row 3 with $(0, 2-a, a-2)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Row 2 was subtracted from row 3. This doesn't change determinant.

Between step 3 and step 4, row 2 was subtracted from row 1, and another $(a-2)$ factored out. So the determinant is the same.

Comment: Well I feel extremely stupid now.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't feel bad about that --- sometimes it takes some staring at things to see what step was done, especially if prof. didn't say what the step was!